# Sending Get Request from a jsp file and getting json response

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I would like to perform a get request from a JSP file and get display the json response.

The link for the get request will look like this :

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search="testicular cancer"
```

However I would like to replace the search parameter with an input parameter from an html form

The html form is in the index.html file:

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <form action="login.jsp" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="disease" placeholder="Enter Disease Name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the login.jsp file I wrote the following code, based on a suggestion to use ajax (from the comments):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function calling(){
         $.ajax({
            url : 'https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search="testicular cancer"',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',// 
            contentType : 'application/json',
            complete : function(response) {
                 console.log(response);  
                }
        });
       }
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Call Servlet" name="Call Servlet"  onclick="calling()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

However I can't see any results when I click the button "Call Servlet". What can I do to correct it?

I am using tomcat in ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: you can use ajax for that , call that url in ajax and get response .

Comment: @Swati Αfter your comment a searched a number of ways, but i cant get it right i am going to update my question with what i have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the onClick from html and add it to jquery on ready like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#callServlet').click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            url : 'https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search="testicular cancer"',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',// 
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);  
                }
            error: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);  
                }
        });
       });
});

<input type="button" value="Call Servlet" id="callServlet" />
```

or just use the `onClick` trigger in html like you have donw now, just make sure to have success as well as error callbacks for ajax.

If you want the json to be displayed in a div with an id like `result` then do like for example :

```
$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Add the above code to the success or error callbacks of an ajax to add the response to the html as json string.

Comment: How do I display the results in the browser though, because with console.log the results display on the console. I tried document.write but it displays as an endless text, not in json format

Comment: Do you need the data to be displayed as a json string in a text area or something ?

Comment: Yes I need them to display in json format on the browser

Comment: @iMaCer98 Have added it in the answer